# How can i use dollar sign to define variable in a string

Tags: javascript

I created 2 `const`; name and age but when I try to print those `const` using dollar sign it didn't show up the result I want. Here's the code

```
const name = 'Tim';
const age = 19;

console.log('My name is ' + name + ' I am ' + age + ' Years old');
const into = 'My name is ${name} I am ${age} Years old';

console.log(into);
```

**here's the result**

> My name is Tim I am 19 Years old                practice1.js:4:9 My
> name is ${name} I am ${age} Years old        practice1.js:7:9

Comment: use ` instead of '

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes. For [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) you have to use backticks

Comment: You have to use backticks if you want to use $ sign to a variable

Comment: omgggg i knewww it, i did a silly mistake. Thanks for your reply! :)